# Loosing wired LAN connection sometimes. Reconnects with 100mbit

Tags: networking, network-manager

I have my Dell XPS13 connected via a CalDigit Pro Dock and sometimes my wired connection gets lost and reengages after a few seconds with only 100Mbit.

dmesg says

````
[Do Feb  9 09:50:27 2023] r8152 6-1.4.4:1.0 enx644bf02bd250: carrier on
[Do Feb  9 09:50:38 2023] r8152 6-1.4.4:1.0 enx644bf02bd250: carrier off
[Do Feb  9 09:50:42 2023] r8152 6-1.4.4:1.0 enx644bf02bd250: carrier on
[Do Feb  9 09:50:50 2023] r8152 6-1.4.4:1.0 enx644bf02bd250: carrier off
[Do Feb  9 09:50:54 2023] r8152 6-1.4.4:1.0 enx644bf02bd250: carrier on
[Do Feb  9 09:50:57 2023] r8152 6-1.4.4:1.0 enx644bf02bd250: carrier off
[Do Feb  9 09:51:06 2023] r8152 6-1.4.4:1.0 enx644bf02bd250: carrier on
[Do Feb  9 09:51:38 2023] r8152 6-1.4.4:1.0 enx644bf02bd250: carrier off
[Do Feb  9 09:51:42 2023] r8152 6-1.4.4:1.0 enx644bf02bd250: carrier on
[Do Feb  9 09:51:58 2023] r8152 6-1.4.4:1.0 enx644bf02bd250: carrier off
[Do Feb  9 09:52:01 2023] r8152 6-1.4.4:1.0 enx644bf02bd250: carrier on
[Do Feb  9 09:52:09 2023] r8152 6-1.4.4:1.0 enx644bf02bd250: carrier off
[Do Feb  9 09:52:22 2023] r8152 6-1.4.4:1.0 enx644bf02bd250: carrier on
[Do Feb  9 09:52:25 2023] r8152 6-1.4.4:1.0 enx644bf02bd250: carrier off```


A modprobe -r r8153_ecm r8152 && modprobe r8153_ecm resolves this but only temporary until it hapens the next time. 


Journal says a lot but I can't make any sense of it. 

```Feb 09 09:52:49 my_computer whoopsie[1526]: [09:52:49] online
Feb 09 09:52:47 my_computer whoopsie[1526]: [09:52:47] offline
Feb 09 09:52:47 my_computer whoopsie[1526]: [09:52:47] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Feb 09 09:52:47 my_computer whoopsie[1526]: [09:52:47] online
Feb 09 09:52:47 my_computer whoopsie[1526]: [09:52:47] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/12
Feb 09 09:52:47 my_computer whoopsie[1526]: [09:52:47] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/12
Feb 09 09:52:47 my_computer whoopsie[1526]: [09:52:47] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/12
Feb 09 09:52:45 my_computer gnome-shell[2667]: [2658:46887:0209/095245.389094:ERROR:get_updates_processor.cc(260)] PostClientToServerMessage() failed during GetUpdates with error 2
Feb 09 09:52:45 my_computer avahi-daemon[1082]: Registering new address record for 2a00:::0:b2b2:f72:12dc:57f9 on enx644bf02bd250.*.
Feb 09 09:52:44 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932764.0126] dhcp6 (enx644bf02bd250): state changed unknown -> bound
Feb 09 09:52:44 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932764.0126] dhcp6 (enx644bf02bd250): option dhcp6_name_servers   => '2a00:e60:2000::241:1 2a00:e60:7000::34:1'
Feb 09 09:52:44 my_computer avahi-daemon[1082]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::67ce:6d01:179d on enx644bf02bd250.
Feb 09 09:52:44 my_computer avahi-daemon[1082]: Registering new address record for 2a00:e67::8e93:5e9b:5b68:57c0 on enx644bf02bd250.*.
Feb 09 09:52:44 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932764.0095] policy: set 'Wired connection 2' (enx644bf02bd250) as default for IPv6 routing and DNS
Feb 09 09:52:44 my_computer avahi-daemon[1082]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enx644bf02bd250.IPv6 with address 2a00:e65:22d:0:8e93:5e9b:5b68:57c0.
Feb 09 09:52:44 my_computer avahi-daemon[1082]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enx644bf02bd250.IPv6 with address 2a00:e65:22d:0:8e93:5e9b:5b68:57c0.
Feb 09 09:52:44 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932764.0076] dhcp6 (enx644bf02bd250): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.7222] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer avahi-daemon[1082]: Registering new address record for 192.168.1.105 on enx644bf02bd250.IPv4.
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer avahi-daemon[1082]: New relevant interface enx644bf02bd250.IPv4 for mDNS.
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.4861] device (enx644bf02bd250): Activation: successful, device activated.
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.4856] policy: set 'Wired connection 2' (enx644bf02bd250) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.4855] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.4845] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.4841] device (enx644bf02bd250): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.4838] device (enx644bf02bd250): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.4811] device (enx644bf02bd250): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer avahi-daemon[1082]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enx644bf02bd250.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.105.
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.4773] dhcp4 (enx644bf02bd250): state changed unknown -> bound
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.4773] dhcp4 (enx644bf02bd250): option subnet_mask          => '255.255.255.0'
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.4773] dhcp4 (enx644bf02bd250): option routers              => '192.168.1.200'
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.4773] dhcp4 (enx644bf02bd250): option requested_wpad       => '1'
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.4773] dhcp4 (enx644bf02bd250): option requested_time_offset => '1'
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.4773] dhcp4 (enx644bf02bd250): option requested_subnet_mask => '1'
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.4773] dhcp4 (enx644bf02bd250): option requested_static_routes => '1'
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.4773] dhcp4 (enx644bf02bd250): option requested_routers    => '1'
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.4773] dhcp4 (enx644bf02bd250): option requested_root_path  => '1'
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.4773] dhcp4 (enx644bf02bd250): option requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes => '1'
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.4773] dhcp4 (enx644bf02bd250): option requested_ntp_servers => '1'
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.4773] dhcp4 (enx644bf02bd250): option requested_nis_servers => '1'
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.4773] dhcp4 (enx644bf02bd250): option requested_nis_domain => '1'
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.4772] dhcp4 (enx644bf02bd250): option requested_ms_classless_static_routes => '1'
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.4772] dhcp4 (enx644bf02bd250): option requested_interface_mtu => '1'
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.4772] dhcp4 (enx644bf02bd250): option requested_host_name  => '1'
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.4772] dhcp4 (enx644bf02bd250): option requested_domain_search => '1'
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.4772] dhcp4 (enx644bf02bd250): option requested_domain_name_servers => '1'
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.4772] dhcp4 (enx644bf02bd250): option requested_domain_name => '1'
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.4772] dhcp4 (enx644bf02bd250): option requested_broadcast_address => '1'
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.4772] dhcp4 (enx644bf02bd250): option ip_address           => '192.168.1.105'
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.4772] dhcp4 (enx644bf02bd250): option expiry               => '1675939962'
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.4772] dhcp4 (enx644bf02bd250): option domain_name_servers  => '192.168.1.200'
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.4772] dhcp4 (enx644bf02bd250): option dhcp_lease_time      => '7200'
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer avahi-daemon[1082]: Registering new address record for fe80::93a6:67ce:6d01:179d on enx644bf02bd250.*.
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer avahi-daemon[1082]: New relevant interface enx644bf02bd250.IPv6 for mDNS.
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer avahi-daemon[1082]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enx644bf02bd250.IPv6 with address fe80::93a6:67ce:6d01:179d.
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.4709] dhcp4 (enx644bf02bd250): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.4706] device (enx644bf02bd250): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.4702] device (enx644bf02bd250): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.4700] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.4697] device (enx644bf02bd250): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.4697] device (enx644bf02bd250): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 2' (a53d3805-d326-3668-b5bd-d143852f4798)
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.4692] policy: auto-activating connection 'Wired connection 2' (a53d3805-d326-3668-b5bd-d143852f4798)
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.4674] device (enx644bf02bd250): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer kernel: r8152 6-1.4.4:1.0 enx644bf02bd250: carrier on
Feb 09 09:52:42 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932762.4665] device (enx644bf02bd250): carrier: link connected
Feb 09 09:52:39 my_computer gnome-shell[2667]: [2658:2912:0209/095239.000762:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(427)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -106
Feb 09 09:52:32 my_computer gnome-shell[6150]: [6143:6174:0209/095232.881101:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(427)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -106
Feb 09 09:52:32 my_computer nm-dispatcher[47900]: run-parts: failed to stat component /etc/network/if-post-down.d/avahi-daemon: No such file or directory
Feb 09 09:52:32 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932752.1453] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Feb 09 09:52:32 my_computer avahi-daemon[1082]: Interface enx644bf02bd250.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Feb 09 09:52:32 my_computer avahi-daemon[1082]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enx644bf02bd250.IPv6 with address fe80::93a6:67ce:6d01:179d.
Feb 09 09:52:32 my_computer avahi-daemon[1082]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::93a6:67ce:6d01:179d on enx644bf02bd250.
Feb 09 09:52:32 my_computer whoopsie[1526]: [09:52:32] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Feb 09 09:52:32 my_computer avahi-daemon[1082]: Registering new address record for fe80::93a6:67ce:6d01:179d on enx644bf02bd250.*.
Feb 09 09:52:32 my_computer avahi-daemon[1082]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enx644bf02bd250.IPv6 with address fe80::93a6:67ce:6d01:179d.
Feb 09 09:52:32 my_computer avahi-daemon[1082]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enx644bf02bd250.IPv6 with address 2a00:e67:52d:0:8e93:5e9b:5b68:57c0.
Feb 09 09:52:32 my_computer avahi-daemon[1082]: Withdrawing address record for 2a00:e67:52d:0:8e93:5e9b:5b68:57c0 on enx644bf02bd250.
Feb 09 09:52:32 my_computer avahi-daemon[1082]: Withdrawing address record for 2a00:e67:52d:0:4985:1395:aade:933e on enx644bf02bd250.
Feb 09 09:52:32 my_computer avahi-daemon[1082]: Interface enx644bf02bd250.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Feb 09 09:52:32 my_computer avahi-daemon[1082]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enx644bf02bd250.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.105.
Feb 09 09:52:32 my_computer avahi-daemon[1082]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.105 on enx644bf02bd250.
Feb 09 09:52:32 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932752.1400] dhcp6 (enx644bf02bd250): state changed bound -> done
Feb 09 09:52:32 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932752.1400] dhcp6 (enx644bf02bd250): canceled DHCP transaction
Feb 09 09:52:32 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932752.1396] dhcp4 (enx644bf02bd250): state changed bound -> done
Feb 09 09:52:32 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932752.1395] dhcp4 (enx644bf02bd250): canceled DHCP transaction
Feb 09 09:52:32 my_computer NetworkManager[1088]: <info>  [1675932752.1157] device (enx644bf02bd250): state change: activated -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 09 09:52:29 my_computer whoopsie[1526]: [09:52:29] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
````